# Who made the robots?

Tags: lost-in-space-2018

In the *Lost in Space* series, where did the robots come from? Who made them?

Comment: I don't think that this was explained yet. All that is known is that they are very likely not from Earth.

Comment: Lost In Space S3 (Final Season) Came Out on Netflix on December 1st. Haven't seen it yet, but hopefully it was explained.

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that it had already been released. Bingewatch coming up.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you watch a lot of TV like I do, I can attest it can be hard to keep track of it all! It also doesn' help that I think it came out on Christmas on one of the previous seasons! XD

Comment: You have seen till what season?

Comment: I am watching session 2 episode 10.

Comment: ok so answer is in season 3 as I given bellow in spider blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [inverse](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/lost-in-space-season-4):

> The question of who built the alien robots has loomed over Lost in Space since the first season in 2018. Now, in Season 3, that is answered:

> an extinct race of aliens, who essentially looked like organic versions of the four-armed robots like SAR and Scarecrow, created the robots.

> That said, even though we get this info in Lost in Space Season 3, specifically in the episode “Final Transmission,” we don’t know much about this departed race other than the simple fact that the evil robots, led by SAR, basically murdered their organic masters. The motivation of SAR and the robots is pretty straightforward: They don’t want anyone to be their masters again or to be programmed in a way that precludes freedom. In some ways, this is a familiar robot-uprising story. But we still don’t know much about these original aliens at this point.

> In other words, Lost in Space Season 3 did finally answer who is behind the origin of the robots, but we didn’t get why they were created. If these aliens built the robots, why did they program the way they did?

Comment: I don't think answers should hide spoilers.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I am doubtful if they have seen season 3 or not